# Media query issue with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, media-queries

This media query should set the div with id of container2 to 50% at screen width 500px. That div has the light_blue and green boxes in it.

Here is the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ofey/1yo4ck9e/1/

SOLUTION: https://jsfiddle.net/ofey/1yo4ck9e/18/

And the css media queries,

```
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
      #boxA {
        order: -1;
        width: 50%;
      }
      .container2 {
        width: 50%;
      }
      #boxB {
        order: 1;
      }
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
      #boxC {
        order: -1;
      }
      #boxB {
        width: 25%;
        order: 2;
      }
      .container2 {
        width: 50%;
      }
      #boxA {
        width: 25%;
        order: 1;
      }
    }
```

and html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box" id="boxA">
      <p>red</p>
    </div>
    <div class="container" id="container2">
      <div class="box" id="boxD">
        <p>light_blue</p>
      </div>
      <div class="box" id="boxC">
        <p>green</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="boxB">
      <p>dark_blue</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I can't see why it doesn't work.

The expected result is that it would look like this at 500px,

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: You have no element that would match the selector `.container2` anywhere in your HTML …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your css, change `.container2` to `#container2` since you use an id.

```
#container2 {
    width: 50%;
}
```

If you also want the container to be on the right, like your image, add `order: 3;`

```
#container2 {
    order: 3;
    width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>media queries</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    .container {
      width: 100%;
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .box {
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
    }

    #boxB {
      background: darkblue;
      color: white;
    }

    #boxD {
      background: lightblue;
    }

    #boxC {
      background: green;
    }

    #boxA {
      background: red;
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
      #boxA {
        order: -1;
        width: 50%;
      }
      #container2 {
        width: 50%;
        order: 3;
      }
      #boxB {
        order: 1;
      }
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
      #boxC {
        order: -1;
      }
      #boxB {
        width: 25%;
        order: 2;
      }
      #container2 {
        width: 50%;
        order: 3;
      }
      #boxA {
        width: 25%;
        order: 1;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box" id="boxA">
      <p>red</p>
    </div>
    <div class="container" id="container2">
      <div class="box" id="boxD">
        <p>light_blue</p>
      </div>
      <div class="box" id="boxC">
        <p>green</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="boxB">
      <p>dark_blue</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I see the class was wrong. Thanks

Comment: I am not sure that order:3 is needed, as this should default to order:0 and so be placed between orders -1 and 1.